# caffe | How to compute an element-wise weighted sum of multiple input blobs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have multiple convolution layers which have the same output shape.
How can I compute an element-wise weighted sum of these layers' outputs in caffe?

Answer (score 2):

For element-wise operations use [`"Eltwise"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/eltwise.html) layer. To achieve a "weighted sum" you can use the `coeff` parameter:

```
layer {
  name: "wsum"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "x1"
  bottom: "x2"
  bottom: "x3"
  top: "y"
  eltwise_param {
    operation: SUM
    coeff: 0.5 # weight for x1 
    coeff: 0.3 # weight for x2
    coeff: 0.2 # weight for x3
  }
}
```

Note that `'coeff'` parameter is only applicapble for `SUM` operation.

Comment: Thanks very much! However, I hope the weights of different layers can be learned, not be fixed.

Comment: @RobinsonDavid in that case you need to add "Scale" layer after every "Conv" layer